# Show all hidden elements when a page loads with override?

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I have a page that forces some JS to load on a page that I need to override.  I can load a separate JS file to do this. I want to have the page do the `.show` for any of the `.below-the-fold`s on the page. I guess the best way to say it is, I want all the "more" things on the page to be expanded when the page loads, rather than making a person click `more` to see what's below the fold on all these.
This is the JS I need to override, I can't change it since it's loaded by the app automatically. There can be more than one of the lists hidden, I'm not sure how much harder that makes things.

```
function MoreFacets($more_facets_div) {
    this.$more_facets_div = $more_facets_div;

    this.bind_events();
};

MoreFacets.prototype.bind_events = function() {
    var self = this;

    self.$more_facets_div.find('.more').on('click', function (e) {
        $(this).siblings('.below-the-fold').show();
        $(this).hide();
    });

    self.$more_facets_div.find('.less').on('click', function (e) {
        $(this).parent().hide();
        $(this).parent().parent().find('.more').show();
    });

};

$(function() {
    $('.more-facets').each(function() {
        new MoreFacets($(this));
    });
});
```

It's loaded on the page and the HTML looks like this:

```
<h3>Additional filters: </h3>
<dl id="facets">
    <dt>Collecting Area</dt>
      <dd> Here's Something in the list</dd>
      <dd> Here's the last in the list</dd>
        <div class="more-facets">
          <span class="more btn">&or; more</span>
          <div class="below-the-fold">
      <dd>Something That's hidden is here</dd>
      <dd>Something more in this hidden list</dd>
```

So when the `&or; more` is clicked is when the others below-the-fold appear, and that's what I want to load when the page loads. There's usually a few different lists like this on the page.

So I'm thinking what I need to do is something like run the `('.below-the-fold').show()` for all the lists when the page loads?

Update A note to clarify: when the page loads now they're all hidden. I'd like them to all show when the page is loaded so no one has to click anything to have everything showing.

Another note based on another question below...  It's loaded in a separate file, and I can load my file before that one. I do know that I can override other JS on the page, so I assume I can override this as well.

Comment: So you want all div with the `below-the-fold` to show when you load the page right? And they are already on the page but hidden ?

Comment: @RomainB. That's correct, when the page loads now they're all hidden. I'd like them to all show.

Comment: Is your JavaScript loaded before or after the script you are trying to fight against, or inline on the page?

Comment: @StephenKennedy It's loaded in a separate file, and I can load my file before that one. I do know that I can override other JS on the page, so I assume I can override this as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your last edit, it sounds like you're already onto the fastest solution to your problem.

Please note, this will only work if the script is not loaded asynchronously, but if you have control of the order the scripts are loaded in, you can insert your script between the problem script and jQuery.

Your script can be something as easy as redefining the function it's using to something like this:

```
MoreFacets.prototype.bind_events = function() {
    var self = this;

    //Autostart in our open state without completely disabling the functionality
    self.$more_facets_div.find('.below-the-fold').show();
    self.$more_facets_div.find('.more').hide();

    self.$more_facets_div.find('.more').on('click', function (e) {
        $(this).siblings('.below-the-fold').show();
        $(this).hide();
    });

    self.$more_facets_div.find('.less').on('click', function (e) {
        $(this).parent().hide();
        $(this).parent().parent().find('.more').show();
    });
};
```

Now, that won't work if you don't have control over the script loading, but you might have hope even in that case, because document ready functions in jQuery are invoked in the order they're registered, so if you can't really control where your script is you might play with an alternative

```
$(function() {
    $('.more-facets').each(function() {
        $(this).find('.below-the-fold').show();
        $(this).find('.more').hide();
    });
});
```

The first will be cleaner, but the second is a fallback for more restrictive situations, and both should achieve your desired effect without completely removing the functionality, just changing the default state on load.

Comment: Thanks so much!! I went with the second one, just because it works and it's much smaller.